# Platform Error: SageMaker pipe channel timed out

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I'm following coursera [AWS sage-maker object detect video](https://www.coursera.org/learn/aws-machine-learning/lecture/lfa8u/amazon-sagemaker-object-detection-on-images-labeled-with-ground-truth). When I used my own image data, the training job encounters "Platform Error: SageMaker pipe channel timed out." error. I didn't find any info related to this error online. Does anybody know what went wrong? The full log is [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1M_3E5gdLvNSR967Vc_u-zg6ixHKaGMN1).

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since you posted this question. The issue you describe sounds very much like an issue we identified and fixed recently so it's likely your issue has been resolved. Could you please try again? If the issue re-occurs we may need some additional detail from you about the training job to be able to look deeper into it for you.